# Access VBA - Clicking button or invoking javascript on website

Tags: javascript, vba, ms-access

I am stumped. I have vba code that fills a website form fields and, for years, has successfully clicked a continue button at the bottom of the page. Recently, the website made changes that have derailed that last step - clicking the continue button.

The HTML code for the button now reads as:

```
<input type="submit" name="PaymentProcessor$ButtonContinue" value="Confirm" onclick="javascript:PaymentProcessor_ButtonContinue.disabled=true;__doPostBack(&#39;PaymentProcessor$ButtonContinue&#39;,&#39;&#39;);WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;PaymentProcessor$ButtonContinue&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="PaymentProcessor_ButtonContinue" class="btn btn-default" style="font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;" />
```

In the past, I have defined ieObj As HTMLInputElement and clicked the button like this:

```
Set ieObj = iePage.getElementById("PaymentProcessor_ButtonContinue")
ieObj.Click
```

Now, that no longer works. I don't get an error, nothing happens. I can see the ieobj get populated in the locals window, so I think I have the correct handle, I just can't manipulate the object.

I have also tried the following:

```
ieObj.FireEvent ("onkeypress")
''no error, no effect
ieObj.FireEvent ("doPostBack")
''error
ieObj.submit
''error- does not support method
ieObj.Value = "continue"
''no error, no effect
ieObj.Value = "confirm"
''no error, no effect
```

I also tried invoking the javascript portion of that html directly, but I am probably doing it wrong:

```
iePage.parentWindow.execScript "document.getElementById('PaymentProcessor_ButtonContinue').submit();", "javascript"
''gives automation error
iePage.parentWindow.execScript "__doPostBack(&#39;PaymentProcessor$ButtonContinue&#39;,&#39;&#39;);WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;PaymentProcessor$ButtonContinue&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false));", "javascript"
''gives automation error
```

I made an effort to utilize queryselector and queryselectorall, but both methods made Access crash.

Elsewhere on the page, the below javascript functions are defined. I don't know if is important, but it is below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['Form1'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.Form1;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>
```

Any Ideas I should try?

Comment: Private webpage / behind login?

Comment: Yeah it is about 5 pages deep into a payment processing website.

Comment: I thin you should view the postback etc as follows: __doPostBack('PaymentProcessor$ButtonContinue','');WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("PaymentProcessor$ButtonContinue", "", true, "", "", false, false)) and some background on the latter part: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.postbackoptions?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8

Comment: DId you also try iePage.parentWindow.execScript "document.getElementById('PaymentProcessor_ButtonContinue').click();", "javascript"

Comment: I tried iePage.parentWindow.execScript "document.getElementById('PaymentProcessor_ButtonContinue').click();", "javascript" at your suggestion.  No error, but no effect.   Thank you for the suggestion.  I read the link in your other comment, but I am not sure how to use that information,

Comment: I think the answer likely lies in correctly executing the cross page JavaScript instruction via the decoded html entities postback string. I’ve not seen an example which combined dopostback and withoptions in client side so you may have to play around with whether and how you combine or pass just one of them.

Comment: That is in relation to my earlier comment where I decoded the html entities

Comment: A less likely option is to create, attach and dispatch an onclick htmlevent

Answer (score 0):

See if the input button is part of a form, and call the form's "Submit" procedure.
Without knowing more about the HTML being scraped, I cannot provide further help.